# Preventing cell height adjustment when rotating 3D graphics

Tags: graphics, faq

I have a large dataset of scattered x,y,z coordinates. I am trying to use `ListPointPlot3D` to identify outliers in 3D. This involves generating a plot and then rotating it to visualise the 'data cloud' and then trying to pick individual triples of interest. Here is an example of my data:

[image: my data]

Using the example from the Document Center (for everyone else's benefit):

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[Sin[i] Cos[j], {i, -5, 5, .25}, {j, -5, 5, .25}], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

[image]

When the graphic is rotated (using a mouse) the cell size changes which causes the whole notebook to re-adjust when the mouse is released making it hard to stay focussed on a particular part of the graphic. Is it possible to prevent the cell size from changing when a 3D graphic is rotated?

Comment: I think you can try `SphericalRegion -> True`

Comment: Also set `ImagePadding -> 15` or some other value, in addition to `SphericalRegion -> True`.  (Without this, the changing axes labels can cause the image to shift.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `RotationAction -> "Clip"`.  You will find that this also [drastically improves interactive rotation performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137195/618728) on complex graphics.  It often produces a lot of extra white space around the plot, but that can be controlled with `ViewAngle` if necessary.  `ViewAngle` by itself will also fix the viewpoint which has the same effect, so you may use that too.

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[Sin[i] Cos[j], {i, -5, 5, .25}, {j, -5, 5, .25}], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 ViewAngle -> 30 Degree
]
```

Comment: This seems to fix the problem nicely! Many thanks.